# Run apps on remote win 10 computer while login active

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, wireless-networking, remote-desktop, remote-access

I have a Windows 10 PC and  Windows 7 laptop.
How can I run applications on my Windows 10 PC, from my Windows 7 laptop, while my daughter is logged onto, and using, the Windows 10 PC?

**Scenario:**
My daughter is playing a game on the desktop Win10. I want to run applications, from my Win 10 account, using my Win 7 laptop. Similar to Linux *rlogin* command.

The computers are connected via wireless network.

Comment: What you describe isn’t possible on consumer editions of Windows.  What you want isn’t possible

Comment: Do you want to run graphical applications, or do you literally want a text-only shell equivalent to rlogin?

Comment: I want to run a graphical application (Visual Studio 2017 IDE, compiler, which is only available on the Windows  10 PC).

Answer (score 0):

This project should work but I’m not sure it is updated with the latest windows 10 builds.

https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap